# How to delete the indexed file from Solr using curl/solrctl command

Tags: solr

I have indexed the multiple text files in Solr using Java code.
Now I have to delete the specific file from Solr Index.
How to do that?

I do not have access on Solr UI.
I have access on the solr server using Putty.
Can someone please help with the command of curl or solrctl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can issue a delete command to Solr via cURL as follows:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/your-core/update?commit=true' --data '<delete><query>id:00020424</query></delete>'
```

You can pass a more complex expression in the `query`.